# How to generate multiple sitemap XMLs by PHP

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, sitemap

My current sitemap file is a too large file that exceeds 50000 URL limit by many times. I have a "sitemap.php" which shows the XML file through htaccess. However, I do not have a clue how to split this sitemap for each 50000 URLs. Seemingly, my "sitemap.php" has to do deal with the splitting action.

Any help would be appreciated...

P.S: sitemap.php is has the code below

```
    <?php
ob_flush();
include ("assets/php/db.php");//bağlantımızı yaptık
header('Content-type: text/xml');

    $domainadi = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //site ismini değişkene aktardık

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
";

echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd">';

$date = date("Y-m-d");

@$xml_ciktisi .= "<url><loc>http://".$domainadi."</loc><lastmod>".$date."  </lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1</priority></url>";

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM cumleler") as $row) {

  $trsef = $row['cumle_tr'];
  $bol = explode(" ",$trsef);
  $bolSay = count($bol);

  for($a=0; $a<=$bolSay; $a++){
  $xml_ciktisi .= "<url>

                     <loc>http://".$domainadi."/ingilizce/".$bol[$a]."</loc>

                          <lastmod>".date( 'Y-m-d' )."</lastmod>

                              <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

                              <priority>0.5</priority>

                              </url>
"; }

  }; 


@$xml_ciktisi .= "<url><loc>http://".$domainadi."</loc><lastmod>".$date."</lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1</priority></url>";

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM cumleler") as $row) {

  $xml_ciktisi .= "<url>

                        <loc>http://".$domainadi."/ingilizce/".$row["cumle_en"]."</loc>

                          <lastmod>".date( 'Y-m-d' )."</lastmod>

                              <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

                              <priority>0.5</priority>

                              </url>
";
   }; 


@$xml_ciktisi .= "<url><loc>http://".$domainadi."</loc><lastmod>".$date."</lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1</priority></url>";

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM ozelders") as $row) {

  $xml_ciktisi .= "<url>

                     <loc>http://".$domainadi."/ingilizce-ozel-ders/profil/".$row["isimsef"]."</loc>

                          <lastmod>".date( 'Y-m-d' )."</lastmod>

                              <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

                              <priority>0.5</priority>

                              </url>
";
  }; 
 $xml_ciktisi .= "</urlset>
";


 echo $xml_ciktisi;
?>
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your sitemap.php please ?

Comment: I think you should store your DB query results in an array, and then use array_chunk() to generate multiple files. See this answer for more informations : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5045502/4098335

Comment: Thanks, I am checking that

Comment: I suggest fetching the record count with an SQL statement first and use `LIMIT` to fetch the database results in chunks. Use `XMLWriter` to create the files. Splitting decreases memory usage but increases the time needed. You will need to find a balance.